# PythonのPlotlyでブラウザーが表示されない

Tags: python, plotly-python

PythonでPlotlyを使って結果を出そうとしています。計算はしてくれるのですが結果の図を表示するブラウザーが開きません。firefoxをアップロードしています。以下のような結果が出ます。

```
/usr/bin/x-www-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found
2023/08/28 18:49:40.242258 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: dial unix /run/user/1000/bus: connect: no such file or directory
Please check the plot on your browser.
I'm here
```

Windows 11 の WSL 環境で、OS は Ubuntu 22.04 です。

Comment: どのような環境・版数・方法・手順で作業を行っていて、どのようなプログラムの何処でどのような問題が発生している・正常ならばこうなるはず等の詳しい情報を追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765), [Getting Started with Plotly in Python](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/)

Comment: 参考: [Running Chrome on Ubuntu Server? How to solve "xdg-settings: not found"?](https://serverfault.com/a/1091931)

Comment: `xdg-settings: not found` はディスプレイシステムが X11 だろうと認識されてて, `xdg-*' 各種コマンドのうち そのコマンドが用意されていないか見つけ出せないでいることを示します。その辺りの詳しい情報がないと回答は付きにくいでしょう。OSは何かとかディストリビューションは何か？とか

Comment: oririさま：ありがとうございます。”OSは”　Windows11　WSLで、”ディストリビューションは ”　Ubuntu22.04です。初心者で申し訳ありませんがこの程度で良いでしょうか？

Comment: @HAFujii 上のコメント（当初は回答として投稿されたもの）のHAFujiiさんは質問者さんと同一人物だと思いますが、アカウントが別になってしまっています。
おそらく、ログイン方法にGoogleアカウントを使うものとパスワードを使うもの、などの違いで意図せず2つできてしまったのだと思います。
質問時に使用したログイン方法でログインし直して、質問を継続できるようにして下さい。
もし、2つのアカウントの統合を希望する場合は、 [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) を参照して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

(microsoft.com) [Linux 用 Windows サブシステム で Linux GUI アプリを実行する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) より

> WSL 2 により、Windows 上での Linux GUI アプリケーションの使用がネイティブで自然に感じられるようになります。

> Windows と Linux のアプリケーションの両方をワークフローに統合し、シームレスなデスクトップ エクスペリエンスを実現できるようになりました。

> **Linux GUI アプリのインストール サポート**
> **前提条件**
> この機能にアクセスするには、Windows 10 ビルド 19044 以降 または Windows 11 である必要があります。
> vGPU 用のインストール済みドライバー
> Linux GUI アプリを実行するには、まずお使いのシステムに合致する以下のプレビュー ドライバーをインストールする必要があります。 これにより、仮想 GPU (vGPU) を使用して、ハードウェア アクセラレータによる OpenGL レンダリングのメリットを享受できます。

> 注意
> WSL での GUI アプリのサポートでは、完全なデスクトップ エクスペリエンスは提供されません。 Windows デスクトップに依存しているため、デスクトップに特化したツールまたはアプリのインストールはサポートされない場合があります。 追加のサポートを要求するには、 GitHub の WSLg リポジトリ で問題を報告します。

---

① まず GUIアプリが本当に動くか確認したほうがよいでしょう
「Gnome テキスト エディター」の例が記されているので, それらが動くのなら大丈夫かも

② 本来の(素の) Ubuntuでは `xdg-*` のコマンドは `/usr/bin/` 以下にあるはず
(Ubuntu 22.04 での例。抜粋)

```bash
$ ls /usr/bin/xdg-* -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42126  8月 22  2022 /usr/bin/xdg-mime
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26075  8月 22  2022 /usr/bin/xdg-open
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38003  8月 22  2022 /usr/bin/xdg-screensaver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38417  8月 22  2022 /usr/bin/xdg-settings
```

もしも `xdg-settings` が入っていないのなら, インストールする必要があるか
もしくは上記の 「**WSL での GUI アプリのサポートでは、完全なデスクトップ エクスペリエンスは提供されません。**」ということかも

③ Firefoxのインストールを行ってみて, 動作確認を行っておくとよいでしょう (注:2)

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
snap install firefox
```

参考:

- [Linux に Firefox をインストールする](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/install-firefox-linux)
- [Installing snap on Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-ubuntu)
- [Firefoxを含むsnapパッケージとの付き合い方](https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0714)

※ 注記
(1) インストールするには, 本来ならば `xdg-utils` パッケージ
(2) (本来の)Ubuntuでの Firefoxパッケージは, 普通は snapsで提供されていて他のアプリと少し異なる方法であり, WSLで それが普通に動くのかどうかわかりません

---

##### 対処方法 (update)

コメントによると, `xdg-utils` パッケージのインストールで解決したようです。(上の ②)
(素の Ubuntuと WSL上の Ubuntuの差異もあり, 推測だったが)
回答(の続き)として追記しておきます

```bash
sudo apt install xdg-utils
```

これにより `xdg-settings` が入り, 動作するようになったのでしょう

Comment: oririさま、ありがとうございました。sudo apt-get install xdg-utils　　xdg-settings のインストールで解決したようです。